# Make ajax call based on change of server response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, comet

I want to make an ajax request when and only when there is a change in server... currently I am using comet technique... I make a request to the server and waits for the response. When the response comes, after one second I again send  request to the server.

I have used angularjs for this process... Here is my code...

```
myapp.run(function(Poller) {});
        myapp.factory('Poller', function($http, $timeout) {

          var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };
          var poller = function() {

        $http.get('http://example.com').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              data.response = data;
              $('.serverStatus').text(data.response.message);
              data.calls++;
              $timeout(poller, 1000);
            });
          };
          poller();

          return {
            data: data
          };
        });
```

But the problem is that it is putting too much load on the server... If I would have thousands of users using my application my server would stuck.

My page should only call the server when there is a change in server (like db, or json etc). Please help me in this

Comment: Take a look at websocket.

Comment: Can you provide a bit piece of code? So that I can understand more

Comment: Why negative rating... I have put my working code here

Comment: because *"Can you provide a bit piece of code? So that I can understand more"* Be willing to do research on your own. that's not what we are here for.

Comment: I have searched alot on net.. but not found much help there... any ways thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a web socket at the server and you can connect using [that](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm)

Comment: Can you provide me list of references? It is only giving HTML5 WebSockets... In this there must be browser compatibility issues etc

Comment: Most of browsers supports html 5, i don't think any kind of compatibility issue

Comment: You're using angular.js. Any browser that supports angular.js will support websockets.

Comment: Thank you... I will try this